# Kafka + SSL ERROR No available authentication scheme for configuration

Tags: docker, ssl, apache-kafka, docker-compose

Trying to run kafka in kraft mode with SSL and have this error during startup.

ERROR Exiting Kafka due to fatal exception during startup. (kafka.Kafka$)
org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No available authentication scheme for configuration A client SSLEngine created with the provided settings can't connect to a server SSLEngine created with those settings.

Also running Elasticsearch Kibana and Kafka Sink Connector using same root CA. If those services are relevant will post them later. Elasticsearch and Kibana working fine. Kafka Connect cant start too because kafka broker is not up.

What I have done. Created rootCA nd certs for broker in .sh script.

```
function generateCA() {

mkdir -p certs

openssl genrsa -out certs/root-ca.key
openssl req -new -key certs/root-ca.key -out certs/root-ca.csr -subj "$CERT_STRING/CN=ekk"

{
echo "\[ekk-root-ca\]"
echo "basicConstraints = critical,CA:TRUE,pathlen:1"
echo "keyUsage = critical, nonRepudiation, cRLSign, keyCertSign"
echo "subjectKeyIdentifier=hash"
} \>certs/root-ca.cnf

openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in certs/root-ca.csr -signkey certs/root-ca.key -out certs/root-ca.crt -extfile certs/root-ca.cnf -extensions ekk-root-ca
}

function generatebrokercert() {

  mkdir broker_certs

  keytool -keystore broker_certs/broker_truststore.jks -import -file certs/root-ca.crt -alias ekk-root-ca -storepass changeit -noprompt

  keytool -keystore broker_certs/broker_keystore.jks -alias broker -keyalg RSA -validity 365 -genkey -storepass changeit -keypass changeit -dname "C=UA,ST=Khm,L=Hyphy,O=Digital,CN=broker" -ext SAN=DNS:broker

  keytool -keystore broker_certs/broker_keystore.jks -alias broker -certreq -file broker_certs/broker-unsigned.crt -storepass changeit -noprompt

  openssl x509 -req -CA certs/root-ca.crt -CAkey certs/root-ca.key -in broker_certs/broker-unsigned.crt -out broker_certs/broker.crt -days 365 -CAcreateserial -passin pass:changeit

  keytool -keystore broker_certs/broker_keystore.jks -alias ekk-root-ca -importcert -file certs/root-ca.crt -storepass changeit -noprompt

  keytool -keystore broker_certs/broker_keystore.jks -alias broker -importcert -file broker_certs/broker.crt -storepass changeit -noprompt

  echo "changeit" > broker_certs/broker_keystore_cred.txt
  echo "changeit" > broker_certs/broker_key_cred.txt
  echo "changeit" > broker_certs/broker_truststore_cred.txt
}
```

---

Here is docker compose file.

```
version: '3.9'

services:

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.5.1
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_NODE_ID: 1
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://:29092,CONTROLLER://:9093
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://broker:9092,OUTSIDE://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:SSL,OUTSIDE:SSL,CONTROLLER:SSL
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1 
      KAFKA_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: SSL
      KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_FILENAME: broker_keystore.jks
      KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_CREDENTIALS: broker_keystore_cred.txt
      KAFKA_SSL_KEY_CREDENTIALS: broker_key_cred.txt
      KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_FILENAME: broker_truststore.jks
      KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_CREDENTIALS: broker_truststore_cred.txt
      KAFKA_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH: required
      KAFKA_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM:
      KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: broker,controller
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: 1@broker:9093
      KAFKA_ENABLE_KRAFT: 'yes'
      CLUSTER_ID: krvJhsSK683B_BWI0KVU1Q
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: CONTROLLER
      KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: /tmp/kraft-combined-logs
    networks:
      - esnet
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: broker_data
        target: /var/lib/kafka/data
      - type: bind
        source: /opt/EKK/broker_certs
        target: /etc/kafka/secrets
    ports:
      - 29092:29092
```